# Relationship between volume and surface charge density in the general case

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge

Assume we have surface $S$ enclosing a volume $V$ and assume the only charge present in this setting is located on the surface, given by a surface charge density $\sigma$. My question is about the correct way to model such a situation in electrostatics and more precisely, what volume charge density $\rho$ we should take in such a case.

There is a related post (here: [Relationship between surface density and volume density](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/135752/relationship-between-surface-density-and-volume-density)) where the problem is discussed in specific examples and it is explained that $\rho$ can in those examples be defined via the Dirac-Delta.

In this question however, I want to know the general "definition" for $\rho$ in such a case, without reference to specific and simple examples like spheres, planes and the like.

My idea is that in the general case of a surface charge, the volume density $\rho$ should be defined as follows: $\rho$ is a distribution with
$$\int_V \varphi\rho \ \text{d}^3x = \int_{S} \varphi\sigma \ \text{da}$$
for all functions $\varphi$ of a suitable function space. Here, "distribution" is understood in the sense of mathematical distribution theory.

**My question** is now simple: Is this the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, though if you want to be super strict, then $\rho$ shouldn't be written inside an integral. You should simply say $\langle\rho,\varphi\rangle:=\int_S\sigma\varphi\,da$, i.e the value of the functional $\rho$ on the test function $\varphi$ is defined to be the integral on the right. This formulation works in any number of dimensions, not just the case of a 2D surface $S$ embedded in $\Bbb{R}^3$.

For instance, let $M$ be a $k$-dimensional embedded submanifold of $\Bbb{R}^n$ ($0\leq k\leq n$), $d\mu_k$ be induced $k$-dimensional volume measure on $M$, and let $\sigma\in L^1(M;d\mu_k)$. We can define a distribution $\delta_{M,\sigma}$ on $\Bbb{R}^n$ by setting for each test function $\varphi$ on $\Bbb{R}^n$ (i.e $\varphi\in C^{\infty}_c(\Bbb{R}^n)$ is smooth compactly supported),
\begin{align}
\langle\delta_{M,\sigma}, \varphi\rangle&:=\int_M\sigma\varphi\,d\mu_k.
\end{align}
We refer to $\delta_{M,\sigma}$ as the **single-layer distribution on the submanifold $M$ with density $\sigma$**. The higher derivatives of this distribution are known as *multiplet-layers* (the "layer" terminology comes from classical PDE solving methods of single and double layer potentials for Laplace's/Poisson's equation).

See analysis/PDE texts for more information about this sort of stuff, for example, Dieudonne's *Treatise on Analysis Vol III* (Chapter 17.10), or Hormander's *The Analyis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I* (Chapter 6.1), or the classic text by Gelfand and Shilov *Generalized Functions Volume I* (Chapter 3.1 is all about distributions on $\Bbb{R}^n$ concentrated  lower dimensional manifolds).